# javascript : post data after click finished

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to do post AJAX request **only once** after color is set for more than 2 seconds.

```
[DEMO FIDDLE]
```

**[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaym0403/zen4ybdx/1/)**

in the fiddle i want AJAX call to be fire **only once** after color is selected.

**i don't want AJAX call to done on every click**

how to do that?

Comment: add flag and check it before sending ajax

Comment: @Grundy can you plz give me working example with my fiddle ?

Comment: you can see @Max answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply add a flag to check if your code ran before.

```js
var timeout; 
var executed;
var arry = ['red', 'blue','orange', 'green'], i=0, len= arry.length;
    $('#element').on('click',function(){  
      $(this).css('background',arry[i++]);
        if(i===len){i=0;}
        if(!executed){
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            timeout = setTimeout(function(){     
                alert("executed");
                executed = 1;
            }, 2000);
        }
    })
```

```css
#element{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element"></div>
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/zen4ybdx/8/)

Comment: This will still be executed for every click, just with a 2 second delay! To achieve the expected result you have to store the timeout, and cancel any previous timeout when you create a new one.

Comment: i want alert to come only once :(

Comment: @kasoban you are right. Forgot to clear the timeout before setting it. Should now be fine.

Comment: @Max your updated fiddle works only once. second time the if i click no alert is coming :(

Comment: @user3030089 thought that was what you wanted to achieve ? What do you mean with **"only once"**?

Answer (score 4):

As you want it to fire only once, bind `.one()` instead of `.on()` to the element. This will make the event execute only once.

And for delay, use `setTimeout()`.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/zen4ybdx/9/. Please upvote and accept the answer if it helped. thanks!

Comment: it only clickes once, i mean only 1 color is changes.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by just adding a condition in your click event as below

```
 $(document).on("click", "#element", function () {
            if ($('body').data("isServerHit") === undefined) {
                $('body').data("isServerHit", true);
                setTimeout(function () {
                  // Write the code for ajax call here
                    alert('server will hit now');
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
```

For more details on `$('body').data("isServerHit", true);`, visit [save data (in jquery)](http://api.jquery.com/data/)

Hope this helps :)